# File is used by another process. How to know which process?

Tags: .net, windows, file-access

I keep getting that exception in my program. How do I know which process locked it, either by program code or by doing something with windows?

`System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file 'file.ext' because it is being used by another process.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use ProcessExplorer to search for the file:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Just run that (maybe you need to launch it with administrator rights), hit `Ctrl-F` and type in the name of the file which is locked - it will find all open handles which match the given name, and tell you which process it belongs to.

Comment: how do I know which process is currently using the file? because when I tried it it looks like it list all recent accesses

Comment: @Louis RH: after starting of the Process Explorer under an account with administrative rights you should press Ctrl-F or choose in the menu "Find" / "Find Handle or DLL..." and then type the name of the file which you search. So just do exactly what Kragen wrote for you.

Comment: @Louis - It may be that processes that access that file don't close it immediately, in which case Process Explorer will find those handles / processes for you - I'm not sure how to work out which of those handles is blocking your use of that file however (not all Handles will block access to a file - two processes can share the same file depending on the access that each process requested - read/write etc...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tool like [`ProcessMon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what process is locking a file.

Comment: This was the only feasible option in my case compared to ResourceMonitor and ProcessExplorer which both assume the blocking application still has a hold of the file by the time I get around to looking up who's blocking on it. In my case I was caught in some temp file switcharoo with MSBuild and apparently mcshield.exe who was doing mischief with my prebuild commands that write to temp batch files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

I use it all the time, tells you which process has locked it and gives you the chance to unlock it fully. Useful especially for when your debugging image manipulation apps and it bombs out without closing the file properly.

Hope this helps!

Sean