# ZipArchiveMode.Update The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

My code is:

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Delete)) 
{ 
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) 
    { 
       addBuilding(archive); 
    } 
    zipToOpen.Close(); 
}
```

When call function on appear next message: The process cannot access the file XXXXX because it being used by another process. How to solved problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File is used by another process. How to know which process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386157/file-is-used-by-another-process-how-to-know-which-process)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code you have shown is not causing this exception.

The error message speaks for itself. In short the file is open somewhere, 9 times out of 10 its your own code that has an operating system file handle open to the file somewhere.

The common causes of this is that you haven't used the `using` statement when dealing with the file.

However its also probable that some other process has the file open, another editor, virus checker can even cause these problems, or any number of things.

Tips

- Check to see if your code opens, edits, or does anything with that file, if it does, make sure you check each method to see if you can possibly use the `using` statement with it. This ensures that the file is closed after it goes out of the scope of the `using` and all managed resources are disposed
- Another simple thing to do is, just restart your computer, this will make sure no other application has exclusive access to it. However if the same problem occurs, then your own code is likely the culprit